# How to access Microsoft Graph from Asp.net Core 1.1 MVC

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I'm taking a summer development course and have been working on writing an API that will allow the user to log in to a personal, work, or school Microsoft.com account and do basic CRUD operations on the events in their calendar. Things like querying for all events within a date range or events that have a specified Open Extension property, etc.

Having finished that, I'm now working on writing a front end for it using ASP.net Core 1.1 MVC. The basic goal here is to list the results of the user's query with a few details, then allow the user to select an event to view all its details, edit it, or delete it. There would be a separate view to allow creation of new events. However, the authentication method I was using prior to switching from a basic console application to ASP.net Core 1.1 MVC (from the Microsoft Graph UWP Snippets located [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-rest-sample/blob/master/O365-UWP-Unified-API-Snippets/AuthenticationHelper.cs)) does not seem to work with ASP.net Core 1.1. Specifically, line 58 from the link above (AcquireTokenSilentAsync()).

I've done a good bit of digging before deciding to come and ask a question here, but I honestly feel like I'm getting nowhere/have been wasting time that I need to be spending on development. For reasons related to the course the professor is very hands-off, so asking him for assistance isn't an option.

How would one go about setting up an ASP.net Core 1.1 MVC app to allow access to the logged-in user's calendar? I've honestly not been able to find much, and since my API is currently very dependent on the token returned from the above Authentication method (it is used with both the HttpClient and GraphServiceClient used in my API) I'm going to need to figure something out soon.

**UPDATE:** I found a tutorial for using OpenIdConnect to log a user in to their Microsoft.com account in Asp.net MVC 6, however I'm not sure if there is a way to get at the authentication token that I need to use the Graph Client/HttpClient. Additionally, I haven't been able to find a similar tutorial for ASP.net Core 1.1 MVC. I'll keep digging and post anything I find here.

**UPDATE 2:** Wasn't having luck with that, have switched to attempting to use the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#2-get-authorization). Currently having a bit of trouble understanding how to get the authorization code to get the access token. If I set `responseMode=query`, do I actually have to query my application's redirect url (in this case localhost:xxxx/) that was created when I registered my app, or is the response automatically returned after the user logs in/consents to letting my app access their data?

**UPDATE 3:** I'm getting closer to having a functioning authentication process by following the steps in the link in Update 2. At this point I guess I'm just curious if my original method of authentication (almost identical to what is contained in the link in my original post) could have worked, or if I was going to find myself in this position no matter what.

Comment: You mentioned that AcquireTokenSilentAsync() fails. Does an exception get caught so the AcquireTokenAsync() method is called on line #70? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-rest-sample/blob/master/O365-UWP-Unified-API-Snippets/AuthenticationHelper.cs#L70

Comment: I actually just finished doing a bit more digging into that. `AcquireTokenSilentAsync()` doesn't _fail_--it simply doesn't work the way that it does in my console app. In the console app version, the only parameter it has is the scope. When I was transferring my authorization code over to the new asp.net core 1.1 app I found it now requires both the scopes, **and** an IUser user--and I have no idea where I'm supposed to get that user object from.

Edit: Nothing changed with `AcquireTokenAsync()` method. I guess in theory I could simply use that in its place? Unsure if it would work the same.

Comment: _"...IUser user--and I have no idea where I'm supposed to get that user object from..."_ 
There is a User static object in all your MVC Controllers. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use most of this sample repository: [Microsoft Graph Webhooks Sample for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-apponlytoken-webhooks-sample) to connect to Microsoft Graph API. It demonstrates using webhooks and MS Graph subscriptions, but it's how it gets the access token that is useful for us.

The relevant code snippet:

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphResourceId, 
    new ClientCredential(AppId, AppSecret)); // For sample purposes only. Production apps should use a client certificate.
return authResult.AccessToken;
```